# Using the iOS9 Compression Framework in Swift2

Tags: ios, compression, zlib, swift2

I have some **NSData** that is stored with the DEFLATE compression protocol?

> DEFLATE Compression Method DEFLATE is a lossless compressed data
>   format that compresses data using a combination of the LZ77 algorithm
>   and Huffman coding, with efficiency comparable to the best currently
>   available general-purpose compression methods. The data can be
>   produced or consumed, even for an arbitrarily long sequentially
>   presented input data stream, using only a priority-bounded amount of
>   intermediate storage. The format can be implemented readily in a
>   manner not covered by patents. Specifications for DEFLATE can be found
>   in RFC 1951 - DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification, May 1996.

If I understand it correctly in IOS9 there is a new [Compression Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/Compression/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/compression_decode_buffer) which "might" handle this case.  The documentation lists the following supported algorithms:  LZFSE, LZ4, LZMA, and ZLIB level 5.

I'm not sure but I believe ZLIB supports the **LZ77** Deflate algorithm.  The question I have is how do I actually use this framework:

So I believe the function i want to use is `compression_decode_buffer`

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func compression_decode_buffer(
    dst_buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, 
    _ dst_size: Int, 
    _ src_buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, 
    _ src_size: Int, 
    _ scratch_buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, 
    _ algorithm: compression_algorithm) -> Int
```

but I'm not sure exactly how to utilize this algorithm.

So from reading the header it looks like i need an input size `dst_size: bytes.size`  and `output size` a `inputBuffer` an `&outputbuffer` and a `compression algorithm`

dst_buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer, 
        _ dst_size: Int, 
        _ src_buffer: UnsafePointer, 
        _ src_size: Int, 
        _ scratch_buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer, 
        _ algorithm: compression_algorithm) -> Int

Assuming i have some sample data (see below)

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [ .... ]  // see below

compression_decode_buffer(
  <DST_BUFFER>,
  <DST_SIZE>, 
  bytes, 
  bytes.count, 
  <SCRATCH_BUFFER>, 
  COMPRESSION_ZLIB
)
```

Where i'm at a loss is as to what goes into **<DST_BUFFER>**, **<DST_SIZE>**, **<SCRATCH_BUFFER>**.

Any suggestions?

#### Sample Data

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x7e, 0x07, 0x07, 0xff, 0xff, 0x41, /* <1~....A */
    0x10, 0x33, 0x51, 0x3e, 0x94, 0xb2, 0xa0, 0x27, /* .3Q>...' */
    0x80, 0x00, 0x21, 0x65, 0x26, 0xd8, 0x22, 0x10, /* ..!e&.". */
    0x2c, 0xd5, 0x99, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xbb, 0xd4, /* ,....D.. */
    0x54, 0x38, 0xf5, 0x01, 0x36, 0xd1, 0x20, 0x2c, /* T8..6. , */
    0xd5, 0x99, 0xbb, 0x1c, 0xaf, 0xc3, 0x2c, 0x60, /* ......,` */
    0xcb, 0x0c, 0x79, 0xcb, 0x76, 0xa0, 0x84, 0xd5, /* ..y.v... */
    0x99, 0x83, 0x1c, 0xaf, 0xc3, 0x2c, 0x60, 0x35, /* .....,`5 */
    0x66, 0x60, 0x49, 0x76, 0x60, 0xc7, 0x5b, 0xf3, /* f`Iv`.[. */
    0xce, 0x05, 0x08, 0x3a, 0x04, 0x13, 0x4a, 0x00, /* ...:..J. */
    0x92, 0x05, 0x08, 0x17, 0x14, 0x68, 0x31, 0xc3, /* .....h1. */
    0x1c, 0xb2, 0xc3, 0x1e, 0x72, 0xdd, 0xe0, 0x00, /* ....r... */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ....'... */
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, /* .......0 */
    0x8e, 0x7e]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data is DEFLATE compressed? I tried various things but could not decompress it. Can you tell how the data was created?

Comment: Ugh - I just looked closer.  This is FIS-B data (aviation data) and it looks like there is a 7e padding on either rend and somewhere in that "blob" is some data. Do you have an example of how to use the DEFLAT in the compression library even if my data is wrong?  That would probably be enough to get me going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally `compression_decode_buffer()` is used like this:

```
import Compression

let bytes : [UInt8] = [ .... ]  // Compressed data
var dst = [UInt8](count: 1000, repeatedValue: 0) // destination buffer
let size = compression_decode_buffer(&dst, dst.count, bytes, bytes.count, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
```

The destination buffer must be large enough for the decompressed data.
On return, `size` is the number of bytes that were written to the 
destination buffer (or zero if the decompression failed).

(There is also a "streaming" interface

```
compression_stream_init()
compression_stream_process()
compression_stream_destroy()
```

which can be used to process the data in chunks.)

However, I tried to decompress your data with all available 
`COMPRESSION_XXX` methods without success.

From my experiments it seems that `COMPRESSION_ZLIB` corresponds
to the "raw deflate" method, i.e. what you get with the zlib 
`deflateInit2()` function if the `windowBits` parameter is set
to a negative value.

Comment: How do you know the size requirements of the buffer? For the same matter, how do you know which of the algorithms in the compression library was used? With the streaming approach at least the data grows organically.

Comment: @user965972 Lee Morgan had some thoughts on this: http://blog.shiftybit.net/2015/07/tinkering-with-compressionlib-part-3/ and he has a sample repository as well: https://github.com/leemorgan/NSData-Compression

Comment: Part 1 of the blog post: "that it’s assumed that the higher level callers will keep this metadata around." So compress the data and prepend it with custom meta data including the file size.

Comment: How big should the decompressed buffer be? I know the size of the compressed data

Comment: @nadi9: Unfortunately there is no function to compute the decompressed buffer sizer in advance, so you can only increase the buffer if necessary. – Or use the streaming interface.

Comment: In my project I am responsible for file compression as well as file decompression. When compressing a file I append a new extension (e.g. .zlib), so when I come to decompressing, I know from the extension that COMPRESSION_ZLIB algorithm was used.